# How can I ensure a Celery task runs with the right settings?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have two sites running essentially the same codebase, with only slight differences in settings. Each site is built in Django, with a WordPress blog integrated.

Each site needs to import blog posts from WordPress and store them in the Django database. When a user publishes a post, WordPress hits a webhook URL on the Django side, which kicks off a Celery task that grabs the JSON version of the post and imports it.

My initial thought was that each site could run its own instance of `manage.py celeryd`, each is in its own `virtualenv`, and the two sites would stay out of each other's way. Each is daemonized with a separate upstart script.

But it looks like they're colliding somehow. I can run one at a time successfully, but if both are running, one instance won't receive tasks, or tasks will run with the wrong settings (in this case, each has a `WORDPRESS_BLOG_URL` setting).

I'm using a Redis queue, if that makes a difference. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you specified the name of the default queue that celery should use? If you haven't set [CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-default-queue) the both sites will be using the same queue and getting each other's messages. You need to set this setting to a different value for each site to keep the message separate.

**Edit**

You're right, CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE is only for backends like RabbitMQ. I think you need to set a different database number for each site, using a different number at the end of your [broker url](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#broker-redis).

Comment: Will this work with Redis? The docs make it sound like this is AMPQ only. I'm still seeing the same issue so far after adding CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE to settings and -Q (with queue name) on the command line.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You're right, that setting is only for AMPQ brokers.

Comment: I think that did the trick. I'd assumed the `CELERY_REDIS_*` settings also set task routing, but it looks like `BROKER_UR`L needs to be set independently from results store.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django-celery then make sure you don't have an instance of celery running outside of your virtualenvs. Then start the celery instance within your virtualenvs using `manage.py celeryd` like you have done. I recommend setting up [supervisord](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/cookbook/daemonizing.html#supervisord) to keep track of your instances.